# Search $needle in $haystack

Tags: c#, asp.net, filepath

I'm using the following to retrieve the script name.

`<%
    String pageName = Request.FilePath; 
%>`

I'd like to be able to check this pageName to see if it contains the value "account".

How do I do this with C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method:

```
if (pageName.Contains("account"))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's easy :D Thank you, stuken.

Comment: The best way to thank someone, is to mark the right answer 'correct answer':)